# UINavigationController use Grouping on TableView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I am using a UINavigationController which creates a tableView automatically.  It currently uses the normal tableView style, but I want to use grouped instead.

How can I set the tableView to group when using a UINavigationController?  There seems to be no answers to this anywhere...

The UINavigationController is inside of a UITabBarController.  All of which was built inside Interface Builder.

Comment: It might be helpful to see how you create the tableview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[UITableViewStyleGrouped](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITableView)

```
 UITableView *aTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:aRect 
                                                        style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

or

```
RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

where `@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController` (taken from adapted [*TableViewSuite, SimpleSectionedTableView*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318)).

[`UITableViewController -initWithStyle:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewController/initWithStyle:)

```
@implementation RootViewController //is a UITableViewController


-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    self.tableView = nil;   
    UITableView *tv = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] 
                                                   style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    self.tableView = tv; 
    [tv release];
}

…
@end
```

Comment: My UINavigationController is inside of a UITabBarController, all of which was build in Interface Builder, so I am not seeing how I could initWithStyle in this case.

Comment: So u can release the tableview in the controllers `viewDidLoad` and create a new tableview as shown in the first example.

Comment: Just do [self.tableView release]; in my class that controller the UINavigationController, then create my own tableView?  Sorry if I am little confused.

Comment: This seems to crash the app and give me a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  Ideas?

Comment: Without seeing ur code I guess i cant tell. How ever I wrote a small code demonstrating it: https://github.com/vikingosegundo/my-programming-examples/tree/master/TabBarNavigator

Comment: Your code helped and it now works.  One last question.  Using autorelease won't be a problem?  Since it will release the tableView sometime in the future?

Comment: The [tableView property of UITableView controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is retaining, therefor `self.tableView = …` will increment the retaincount by 1, `alloc/int` too. so autorelease will lead to retaincount 1, and UITableViewController will finally decrement it to 0 in `viewDidUnload/dealloc`

Comment: after discussing with a very experienced colleague I factored the autorelease out. see https://github.com/vikingosegundo/my-programming-examples/blob/master/TabBarNavigator/Classes/FirstViewController.m

Comment: The new example works great, and the code look much better.  Thank you!